# run grpc python example must use sudo command

Tags: python, grpc, grpc-python

Depend on this tutorials [grpc basic](https://grpc.io/docs/tutorials/basic/python.html)

I clone `https://github.com/grpc/grpc` to local,

`cd example/python/helloworld`
start server `python greeter_server.py`

then start client `python greeter_client.py`, 
but get error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "greeter_client.py", line 35, in <module>
  run()
  File "greeter_client.py", line 30, in run
    response = stub.SayHello(helloworld_pb2.HelloRequest(name='you'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 533, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 467, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline) grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
      status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
      details = "Socket closed"
      debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1541228979.471085000","description":"Error received from peer","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1017,"grpc_message":"Socket closed","grpc_status":14}"
```

then I execuse `sudo python greeter_client.py`, get the correct result.

Why I should add sudo to get the correct result?

Comment: I use python2 and python3 get the same error

Comment: Can you provide more information about your environment? This seems like most likely a machine configuration issue, so it would also be helpful if you could rule out a local configuration problem by checking if a non-gRPC server/client on the same port will work.

Comment: I have same issue. unfortunately "sudo" doesn't help; i am running it on ubuntu16.04.  I can run this example inside centos 7 docker containers

Comment: I found I set a global http proxy, so I change 'localhost' to '127.0.0.1', it's fine.

Comment: I had a similar error, when i was trying to connect to a secure port with an insecured channel, so keep that in mind too.

Answer (score 1):

1. I found I set a global http proxy `export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:1087`, I closed this proxy, then It was find.
2. update `greeter_client.py`, change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`. It's find to me.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try few options and share your feedback:

**Option - 1**

another port(except 50051) in [client](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/python/helloworld/greeter_client.py) and [server](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/python/helloworld/greeter_server.py#L36)?

**Option-2**

Try with 0.0.0.0 in [client](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/python/helloworld/greeter_client.py)

Thanks,
Dheeraj